# Android Toolbar item OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, toolbar

I have a Toolbar and an item (add) which, when clicked, adds a view in listView below. However, the `onOptionsItemSelected` gives you the effect of a single click so it only adds one view, and in my case, I need multiple views, thus multiple clicks are required. How do I set up everything so that the item behaves as an `onClickListener` rather than a single click?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.addButton){
        final TextView noProject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NOPROJECT);

        final ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
        final ListAdapter addAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.list_item, R.id.listFrame, listItems);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(addAdapter);

        noProject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listItems.add("New Project");
        ((ArrayAdapter) addAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    if (id == R.id.addPeople) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: 1) Why Java 6 syntax? 2) Do not add a new ArrayAdapter each time.

Answer (score 0):

Android is always listening for menu item clicks. And on click your action will happen, so you'll need to click multiple times anyways if you want this add feature in the menu.

I usually setup my list adapter in onCreate or onCreateView. Once it's established you can do addAdapter.clear() and addAdapter.add(item). You shouldn't need to reference your listitems directly since the ArrayAdapter.add() method is setup to append to that list anyways and then if i'm not mistaken you can get rid of notifyDataSetChange() - I've never had to use this method with any of the default list adapters or the custom adapters I've written. .clear(), .add(), .insert(), and .remove() should be sufficient.

My listview is usually filled out using a for loop. If you want multiple views added then could you just setup a loop instead of waiting/requiring for more clicks?

Maybe I'm not fully understanding the usecase but a basic for loop seems like the answer here.

Edit:

```
//For Each Loop - "For each individualItem in itemHolder"
listadapter.clear();
for(ItemType individualItem : itemHolder){
    listAdapter.add(individualItem.getText());
}
```

or you can do a traditional for loop

```
//"For i(index) starting at index 0, run until index < itemHolder.getItemCount() is false"
//for(initialize index variable : condition check : increment after each     iteration)
for(int index =0; index<itemHolder.getItemCount(); index++)
{
  listAdapter.add(itemHolder.getItemAt(index));
}
```

Something like that. I made up method names obviously it's going to depend on your data structures.

Comment: Haven't done much with for loops, but i'll see what I can do, thanks :)

Comment: Ok added an ultra basic example of how they might be used in this scenario. Good luck. Loops are an essential structure in every programming language I've ever used so you should definitely get comfortable with them.